# Disable DTC tracking in RavenDB with Voron storage

Tags: ravendb, msdtc

We are experimenting with using RavenDB as a log target within our current NLog usage.  We created a new RavenDB server and a database using Voron as the storage engine.  Then it was just a matter of updating our nlog configurations, which we did.

For a while, everything was great, but then we ran into a situation where we are running calling Trace() within a database transaction.  With ravenDB setup as the log target, this means the SaveChanges() call is made within the transaction as well.

Everything is great until we call Transaction.Commit().  RavenDB throws a 500 server error at that point, because DTC is not supported with the Voron engine (and is slated to be removed everywhere, from what I understand).  I'm fine with this.  I don't particularly care - writing to the log should not be part of the transaction anyway, because if something does go wrong, we don't want to remove the related log entries.

I searched the documentation hoping to find a configuration option that I could set that would just tell RavenDB to ignore transactions, or at least ignore DTC, but I can't find anything. Is there anyway I can get it to stop throwing these 500 server errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `EnlistInDistributedTransactions = false` on the document store, and it will work for you

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I think my search of the site failed because I was using the acronym 'DTC' instead of other search terms.